# How to multiple checked by Click on checkbox and checked multiple two or three check box by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> This is Item 1</li>
<li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> This is Item 2</li>
<li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> This is Item 3</li>
<li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> This is Item 4</li>
<li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> This is Item 5</li>
<li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> This is Item 6</li>
```

I want to click on a checkbox, then check in multiple checkboxes or one or three checkboxes will be auto checked. How can i do?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. Could you edit it to include your desired output and show the attempts you've made to solve this yourself

Comment: @Mamun sir, i have done all select checkbox but i want to click one checkbox then select multiple checkbox or two or three check.

Comment: Your words are not understandable, you do not have any attempted code as well so that someone can predict the issue you are facing.

Comment: @ali541 you are going to need to use Javascript in order to make that happen. Using an OnClick function and assign some ids to your input. If you gave an example it would help clarify things a bit.

Comment: You need to be good at google search, if you search a little you will find lot of resource, this is for binding event to checkbox https://api.jquery.com/change/ and this is for checking other checkboxs https://stackoverflow.com/a/426276/2060913

Answer (score 0):

1.First you should add ids or names for each checkbox.
2.Create a function that checks which checkbox is checked and implement your logic.